# Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV in python 3

Tags: python

I wanna to know how to fix this code for python 3:

```
# white balance for every channel independently
def wb(channel, perc = 0.05):
mi, ma = (np.percentile(channel, perc), np.percentile(channel,100.0-perc))
channel = np.uint8(np.clip((channel-mi)*255.0/(ma-mi), 0, 255))
return channel

image = cv2.imread("_NHL0591.jpg", 1) # load color
imWB  = np.dstack([wb(channel, 0.05) for channel in cv2.split(img)] )
```

but i get error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Sample\1.py", line 7, in 
> image = cv2.imread("_NHL0591.jpg", 1) # load color
> NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
> [Finished in 60ms]

Comment: did you import it? that's not a `ModuleNotFoundError` but a `NameError`.

Comment: i'm try to import but still error on python 3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your code:

```
import cv2
```

And probably you need to install it (before importing it), in command prompt:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

And checks if installation is successful

**EDIT**

As you are installing for python 3 you can try:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

> You have to use pip3 for it to be installed on Python3. So to install
> packages in python3, you should use pip3. NOTE:- Its not necessary
> that pip will install in python 2.7, if python2 is absent then pip
> will do it in python3. The above statement was if you have both the
> version of python installed.

Comment: I installed opencv and numpy but still error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Sample\1.py", line 9, in <module>
    imWB  = np.dstack([wb(channel, 0.05) for channel in cv2.split(img)] )
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
[Finished in 310ms]

Comment: Did you `import numpy as np`?

Comment: yes, i imported numpy as np

Comment: Edited my answer, please check it it helps.

Comment: i got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Compressed\Sample\1.py", line 11, in <module>
    imWB  = np.dstack([wb(channel, 0.05) for channel in cv2.split(img)] )
NameError: name 'img' is not defined
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
[Finished in 739ms]

Comment: I think it's another problem already